# pip install a python package and dependencies .whl file from local pypi (JFROG artifactory) using Jenkinsfile

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm having trouble installing the dependencies of a Python wheel from Artifactory on my Jenkins job. It seems to be finding and pulling the correct .whl file, but it doesn't seem to be installing its dependencies. I get this error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://biv_ci_id:****@docker.repo1.uhc.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
Collecting ness_logger_lib
  Downloading https://docker.repo1.uhc.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/smart-audit/ness_logger_lib-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement avro-python3 (from ness-logger-lib) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for avro-python3
```

I'm trying to run unit tests for an application that needs the wheel listed above. I'm doing this during the testing stage of a Jenkins job. The stage that fails on my Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
stage('Python Unit Testing') {
    agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
    steps {
        sh '''
            export PYTHON_VERSION=${PYTHON_VERSION}
            . /etc/profile.d/jenkins.sh
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            python3 -m ensurepip
            python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
            python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
            python3 -m pip install ness_logger_lib -i https://${ci_id}:${ci_pass}@docker.repo1.uhc.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
            pytest ./sa_create_run_job --cov=./sa_create_run_job/server --cov-report=xml
        '''
        archiveArtifacts 'coverage.xml'
        stash includes: 'coverage.xml', name: 'py-coverage'
    }
}
```

As you can see from the error, its able to find and pull the wheel from Artifactory just fine, but it doesn't seem to be able to find the dependencies. Manually installing those dependencies first, like so, seems to work around the problem:

```
  steps {
  sh '''
      export PYTHON_VERSION=${PYTHON_VERSION}
      . /etc/profile.d/jenkins.sh
      python3 -m venv venv
      . venv/bin/activate
      python3 -m ensurepip
      python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
      python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      python3 -m pip install avro-python3
      python3 -m pip install kafka-python
      python3 -m pip install netaddr
      python3 -m pip install pathlib
      python3 -m pip install psutil
      python3 -m pip install requests
      python3 -m pip install ness_logger_lib -i https://${ci_id}:${ci_pass}@docker.repo1.uhc.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
      pytest ./sa_create_run_job --cov=./sa_create_run_job/server --cov-report=xml
  '''
  archiveArtifacts 'coverage.xml'
  stash includes: 'coverage.xml', name: 'py-coverage'
  }
```

However, this is pretty inconvenient, especially since we plan to use this wheel for multiple applications.

How can I ensure that the wheel's dependencies are installed automatically, when pulling from Artifactory's `pypy-local`?

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You have to use the `--extra-index-url` option of `pip` instead of `-i / --index-url` (see `pip help install` and look for the `Package Index Options:` section)

```
python3 -m pip install ness_logger_lib \
--extra-index-url https://${ci_id}:${ci_pass}@docker.repo1.uhc.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
```

## Background info

I have to take a guess here but I'm pretty sure your local pypi is not an actual mirror of pypi but only contains a few extra packages. Moreover, from the rest of your commands we can see that you have access to the default pypi.org index.

If my guess is correct, you are using pip wrongly, i.e. you are replacing the default pypi.org index with you own (and incomplete) index. Pip finds you explicit custom package on your custom index but then tries to resolve the dependencies on that same index and fails.

When you replace the `-i` option with `--extra-index-url`, you instruct pip to look in both indexes for your packages. It will then find your local package in your artifactory index and the dependencies in the default pypi.org index.